# cygwin + $PATH + adding path to configuration

Tags: path, cygwin

which one of these files do I have to edit so that I can launch Notepad++ from my cygwin Terminal?

```
$ find -name ".*"
.
./.bashrc
./.bash_history
./.bash_profile
./.inputrc
./.profile
```

This is the command I give in the terminal to add the Notepad++ to the directory

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/
```

So if i do a `echo $PATH` I can see that the directory was added to my PATH

This then allows me to open files in Notepad++ for editing

```
$ notepad++.exe filename
```

But i want my cygwin to be like this everytime I launch it. How can this be done?

**NOTE:** Using cygwing on windows7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also another ways to do what you want. You don't have to add Notepad's directory to the `PATH`, when you need only one executable from that directory. The main advantage of a directory in the `PATH` is that every executable in that directory is available anywhere.

You can use for example **alias**, **symbolic link** or **function**. Each method creates the "*npp*" command, which you can then use as you suggested: `npp filename`. Advantage over the `PATH` method is that you can name it whatever you want.

### alias

`alias npp='/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'`

You can put it for example to your `.bashrc`. You can also add a parameters to an alias command. The name of an alias can be whatever you want.

### symbolic link

`ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe /usr/local/bin/npp`

This will create a file in the directory `/usr/local/bin` which is already in your `PATH`. This file is symbolic link (something like Windows' shortcut) to the Notepad++ executable. The name of a symbolic link (the last part of the command) can be whatever you want, but you can't use a parameters there.

General format of the `ln` command for symbolic link:

`ln -s target link_name`

### function

```
npp () {
    /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe $(cygpath -w -- "$@")
}
```

Again, you can put it for example to your `.bashrc` and name it whatever you want. `cygpath` converts path to the file from Linux to the Windows format, but it should not be necessary.

Comment: similarily to the `alias` way would I put the `symbolic link` in the .bashrc file?

Comment: @HattrickNZ: no, it's a persistent operation. It works the same way as Windows' shortcut works. You have to create it only once too. So just execute the command I have described in the command line. It will create the symbolic link file. `.bashrc` content is processed always you execute bash, so for example always you open a new console. So it's pointless to put it to `.bashrc`, but it would work too.

Comment: @HattrickNZ: if you have found my answer useful, please consider marking it as answer or voting for it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting a "Permission Denied" error.  I've gone through and change the ownership of the entire Notepad++ folder to my user, and even set a "chmod 777", but still no luck.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @swv `/usr/local/bin` is the folder that you need write permissions in

Answer (score 2):

By editing ./bashrc file, you can achieve your goal. Here is the link for [Cygwin Tutorial: Use External Editor Notepad](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/cygwin-tutorial-use-external-editor-notepad/).